# git push when there are untracked files

Tags: git, gitlab

Can I git push to a repository if I still have untracked files?

Note: I am **not** asking how to add untracked files to the stage and commit them *before* pushing them.

I don't want those untracked files, they are undesired and have just appeared after a test. They should have been ignored (somehow the .gitignore file was not correct I suppose).

So my question is, even though after doing `git status` I see there are untracked files, can I still push my files to the repository?

Comment: have you tried it? Untracked files are things git does not know/care about (except to report they exist, in `git status`). Please self answer when you do :)

Comment: it is obvious I don't have access to the machine right now, therefore I am asking to a *sharing of knowledge*

Comment: As many developers I think of the projects I am working on even when I am not in front of  the pc. My latest situation is the one described and I have been thinking what to do. I made a search in my phone but could not get an answer. So I am asking directly if I can git push in that situation. Can I?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the untracked files, you should look into `git clean`. This will help clean up your untracked files- otherwise they will keep showing up in your git status until you do something about them.

They won't affect pushing- only time I would see it affect pushing is if you use `git add .` before committing and pushing and forget about those untracked files- then they become part of your commit.

Answer (score 3):

The `git push` command pushes *commits*, not files.  Commits of course *contain* files, so whatever files are in the commits that go in, are in—but an *untracked file* is by definition a file that is not *currently* in Git's *index*.  Git makes new commits from its index, not from your work-tree.  So if those files aren't in Git's index now, they probably weren't in Git's index earlier, and hence will not be in any earlier-made commits either.

(You can inspect the complete set of files in any given commit using `git ls-tree -r`: supply an identifier for that commit, e.g., a branch name like `master`, or a branch name with a relative suffix, like `master~2`, or a raw hash ID.  If you have not been deliberately adjusting Git's index as you work, though, the fact that they're not in the index now is usually enough of an indicator that you don't need to check.  It won't hurt to check, but usually it's easier to check with `git log --name-status` or `git log --raw`.  The `--raw` output used to be obtained by `git whatchanged`, back in the early days of Git, and it's actually still one of the styles I prefer.)

Answer (score 2):

yes you can push only the files which you have commited before. you can leave the untracked files and adapt them later.